# Why does Acrobat Reader under MacOS display the wrong size of media generated with the media9 package?

Tags: viewers, media9

I regularly include media by means of Alexander Grahn's nice media9 package. In particular I include .u3d-files. Recently I experienced that Adobe's Reader under MacOS doesn't display the included u3d-graphics in the right size (which it did before):
A change of the values for the variables "width" and "height" in the includemedia-command has only effect up to a certain size. (You cannot increase over that bound.) The media always appears in a rather small box on the left lower corner of the respective page. The funny thing is: When I open the generated pdf-file with Adobe Reader under MS Windows everything is fine -- the media window has the size I adjusted. This indicates that this is an issue of the Mac-version of Acrobat Reader.

Detailed information:
I use the most recent version of Acrobat Reader DC (Version 2021.011.20039) under both operating systems, namely MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 and Windows 8.1.

Any idea what could be the reason for that issue?

Thanks in advance,
Anton

Comment: Hard to say. How do the 3D examples in the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf) look like in A-Reader?

Comment: Same behavior: I opened your manual "media9.pdf" (version from Oct. 2021) with Adobe Reader, once under MacOs and another time under Windows 8.1. Then the 3 examples for embedding 3D-objects provided in Fig. 9, p. 32, Fig. 10, p.33 and Fig. 11, p.34 show different behavior. First of all the size of the 3D-window is muchs maller under MacOs than under

Comment: That sounds weird and looks like a bug in AR. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a box with MacOS and thus cannot test myself. Did you consider sending a bug report? What about older AR versions under MacOS, did they display 3D content correctly?

Comment: Yes, former versions of AR under Mac displayed everything in the correct way. (I already use the u3d-embedding via media9 since several years.) So maybe I should send something to Adobe. Although my experience with such bug reports is rather, that they don't have any effect.

Comment: In the meantime I visited a forum on Adobe's page and the reason for the issue has become clearer: It is a matter of the render-method used. You can choose the render method of AR in Edit > Preferences > 3D & Multimedia. On my machine "DirectX 9" is used as render tool under Windows whereas under Mac I have OpenGL 1.4. The bad thing is that I cannot choose "DirectX" under Mac. (There is only one other option beside OpenGL 1.4, namely "Software".